# Dropbox python API, download of file with associated comment

Tags: api, dropbox

I have a bunch of jpgs in Dropbox, each jpg will have a comment associated. How do I download, by  the python API, the comment associated with the  jpg?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer access to comments, but I'll be sure to pass this along as a feature request.